# how to change 39.54484700000000 to 39.54 and using python

Tags: python, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

i want to set `39.54484700000000` to `39.54`  using python ,

how to get it ,

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "change"?  From your question, we can't guess.  Both could strings.  Then you're doing a string slice.  Both could be float, so you're truncating.  The first could be float and the second string and you're formatting.   The first could be string and the second float, in which case you're converting and rounding.  This question cannot be answered in this form.  Fix it, please.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to change the actual value, use `round` as Eli suggested. However for many values and certain versions of Python this will not result be represented as the string "39.54". If you want to just round it to produce a string to display to the user, you can do

```
>>> print "%.2f" % (39.54484700000000)
39.54
```

or in newer versions of Python

```
>>> print("{:.2f}".format(39.54484700000000))
39.54
```

or with the fstrings

```
>>> print(f'{39.54484700000000:.2f}')
39.54
```

Relevant Documentation: [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), [Built-in Functions: round](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round)

Comment: but i dont want get the string '39.54'  , i want get the `number` 39.54

Comment: The way that an ordinary number is stored in Python cannot accurately represent the value 39.54 (because it is a base-10 value that does not have a finite base-2 representation). You can either use the decimal.Decimal class as suggested by others, or upgrade to a version of Python which converts the imprecise value to the string that you want (CPython2.7+, IIRC).

Comment: first of all, thanks for posting links to the actual documention. however, i cant seem to find anything regarding the `'{:.2f}'.format(n)`, specifically the `:.` syntax in the documentation? what does the `:.` do exactly and can you point me to the part of the documentation that touches on this?

Answer (score 3):

How about `round`

```
>>> import decimal
>>> d=decimal.Decimal("39.54484700000000")
>>> round(d,2)
39.54
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [quantize](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html?highlight=quantize#decimal.Decimal.quantize) method if you're using a Decimal:

```
In [24]: q = Decimal('0.00')

In [25]: d = Decimal("115.79341800000000")

In [26]: d.quantize(q)
Out[26]: Decimal("115.79")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `round`:

> Return the floating point value x
>   rounded to n digits after the decimal
>   point. If n is omitted, it defaults to
>   zero. The result is a floating point
>   number.
>   Values are rounded to the closest
>   multiple of 10 to the power minus n;
>   if two multiples are equally close,
>   rounding is done away from 0

```
>>> round(39.544847, 2)
39.539999999999999
>>>
```

Note that since 39.54 isn't exactly represantable with floating points on my PC (x86), the result is an epsilon off. But that makes no difference (and is a whole different issue with many SO questions and answers on it). If you convert it to a string properly, you'll see what you expect:

```
>>> "%.2f" % round(39.544847, 2)
'39.54'
```

Comment: but , i want geta short number, not a long number .

Comment: @zjm1126: in what sense? do you want to print it out? then just use the %.2f format

Comment: @EliBendersky: Isn't "%2.f" already rounding? So you're rounding twice as it appears.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> round(39.54484700000000, 2)
39.54
```

Note, however, that the result isn't actually 39.54, but 39.53999999999999914734871708787977695465087890625.

Answer (score 2):

Eli mentions using the round function -- depending on your requirements, you may want to return a Decimal object instead.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> float_val = 39.54484700000000
>>> decimal_val = Decimal("%.2f" % float_val)
>>> print decimal_val
39.54
```

Using Decimal objects lets you specify the exact number of decimal places that you want to keep track of, so you avoid ending up with a floating point number that is represented as `39.539999999999999`. Specifically, if you are doing financial calculations, you will almost always be advised to stay away from floating-point numbers.

You can't cast floats directly into Decimals, however (the floats are imprecise, and Python can't guess how you want them rounded,) so I will almost always convert them to a rounded string representation first (that's the `"%.2f" % float_val` -- `%.2f` means to display only two decimals, and then create a Decimal out of that.

Comment: it will be show Decimal("39.54") , but i dont want to get the `Decimal`

Comment: @zjm1126: Did you try `print`ing it? `print` should cast the Decimal object to a string, and its string representation is just "39.54"